# SQL server select oldest records where width column is within specific range of each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have table with the following format

```
   vend_plate_no |  width       |   received_date
   --------------|--------------|---------------    
   PE9334-1      |  60          |   March 16, 2015
   PE9334-2      |  60          |   March 16, 2015
   PE9334-3      |  60          |   March 16, 2015
   PE9545-1      |  60          |   March 20, 2015
   PE9545-2      |  60          |   March 20, 2015
   PE9530-1      |  60.375      |   March 10, 2015
   PE9530-2      |  60.375      |   March 10, 2015
   PE9530-3      |  60.375      |   March 10, 2015
   DP5603-5      |  61.3        |   April 29, 2015
   PF2207-1      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2207-2      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2207-3      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2207-4      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2208-1      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2208-2      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2208-3      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
   PF2208-4      |  61.375      |   May 26, 2015
```

Can I select the oldest x records where the width is within y inches of each other?  I cannot specify the bottom and top width value because my data set has many more width values then the sample data set I've provided above, so I must be able to search the entire width column (starting with the oldest records) until I find a specific number of rows where the width is different by .25 inches higher or .25 inches lower.  For example can I select the 9 oldest records that are within .25 inches width of each other?  Given those conditions, the result set using the data set above would be as follows:

```
vend_plate_no | width       |   received_date
--------------|-------------|---------------    
DP5603-5      |  61.3       |   April 29, 2015
PF2207-1      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2207-2      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2207-3      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2207-4      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2208-1      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2208-2      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2208-3      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
PF2208-4      |  61.375     |   May 26, 2015
```

But if I select the 5 oldest records that are within .25 inches width of each other the result set using the data set at the top of this post would be this:

```
vend_plate_no | width        |  received_date
--------------|--------------|---------------   
PE9334-1      | 60           |  March 16, 2015
PE9334-2      | 60           |  March 16, 2015
PE9334-3      | 60           |  March 16, 2015
PE9545-1      | 60           |  March 20, 2015
PE9545-2      | 60           |  March 20, 2015
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what you have tried so far ??

Comment: what is the unit of your width column?? inches?

Comment: Can there be multiple records with the same `vend_plate_no` ?

Comment: The vend_plate_no column values are unique, for all records.  yes the width column is in inches with at most 3 decimal places rounded to the thousandths of an inch.

Answer (score 2):

I think this produces the results you want. Hopefully, I've broken it down into enough CTEs so that you can see my thought processes here.

```
declare @t table (vend_plate_no varchar(19), width decimal(18,3), received_date date)
insert into @t (vend_plate_no,width,received_date) values
('PE9334-1',60,'20150316'),('PE9334-2',60,'20150316'),('PE9334-3',60,'20150316'),
('PE9545-1',60,'20150320'),('PE9545-2',60,'20150320'),('PE9530-1',60.375,'20150310'),
('PE9530-2',60.375,'20150310'),('PE9530-3',60.375,'20150310'),('DP5603-5',61.3  ,'20150429'),
('PF2207-1',61.375,'20150526'),('PF2207-2',61.375,'20150526'),('PF2207-3',61.375,'20150526'),
('PF2207-4',61.375,'20150526'),('PF2208-1',61.375,'20150526'),('PF2208-2',61.375,'20150526'),
('PF2208-3',61.375,'20150526'),('PF2208-4',61.375,'20150526')

declare @SetSize int
declare @Tolerance decimal(18,3)

select @SetSize = 9, @Tolerance = 0.25

;With Numbered as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY received_date) rn
    from @t
), SetNumbers as (
    select 1 as nn union all select nn+1
    from SetNumbers where nn < @SetSize
), Groups as (
    select *,(rn - nn) + 1 as GroupNumber
    from Numbered cross join SetNumbers
), Collected as (
    select COUNT(*) as cnt,GroupNumber,MIN(width) as minWidth,MAX(width) as MaxWidth
    from Groups group by GroupNumber
    having COUNT(*) >= @SetSize and MAX(width) - MIN(width) <= @Tolerance
), Earliest as (
    select top 1 GroupNumber from Collected order by GroupNumber
)
select vend_plate_no,width,received_date
from
    Groups g
        inner join
    Earliest e
        on g.GroupNumber = e.GroupNumber
```

That is, `Numbered` first assigns row numbers to the rows so that we can easily identify groups. `SetNumbers` generates the set of numbers from `1` to `@SetSize`.

We then join these two CTEs together in `Groups` and produce `GroupNumber` values - this is probably the trickiest bit. The `GroupNumber` is, essentially, the row number (`rn`) for a row that the current row *could* be part of a set with, in order to satisfy the requirements.

Having armed ourselves with these `GroupNumber`s, we can now combine rows based on these (`Collected`), and ask ourselves (via the `HAVING`) whether that specific group of rows does satisfy the requirements.

Finally, we peel off the earliest such matching group (`Earliest`) and combine it back with the `Groups` set, which is a set of rows that still contains the original columns of interest.

Result:

```
vend_plate_no       width                                   received_date
------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------
DP5603-5            61.300                                  2015-04-29
PF2207-1            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2207-2            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2207-3            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2207-4            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2208-1            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2208-2            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2208-3            61.375                                  2015-05-26
PF2208-4            61.375                                  2015-05-26
```

And result if we change `@SetSize` to 5:

```
vend_plate_no       width                                   received_date
------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------
PE9334-1            60.000                                  2015-03-16
PE9334-2            60.000                                  2015-03-16
PE9334-3            60.000                                  2015-03-16
PE9545-1            60.000                                  2015-03-20
PE9545-2            60.000                                  2015-03-20
```

Comment: Wow Damien, you NAILED IT!  Thanks a ton man, solved a huge problem and provided a ton of education!  This works great